# Lucene.net - can't do a multiword search

Tags: c#, lucene

I have stored the following documents in my lucene index:

```
{
"id" : 1,
"name": "John Smith"
"description": "worker"
"additionalData": "faster data"
"attributes": "is_hired=not"
},
{
"id" : 2,
"name": "Alan Smith"
"description": "hired"
"additionalData": "faster drive"
"attributes": "is_hired=not"
},
{
"id" : 3,
"name": "Mike Std"
"description": "hired"
"additionalData": "faster check"
"attributes": "is_hired=not"
}
```

and now I want to seach over all the fields to check if the given value exists:

```
search term: "John data check"
```

which sould me return the documents with `ID 1 and 3`. But it doesn't, why ?

```
var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);

BooleanQuery mainQuery = new BooleanQuery();
mainQuery.MinimumNumberShouldMatch = 1;

var cols = new string[] {
                         "name",
                         "additionalData"
                        };

 string[] words = searchData.text.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

 var queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, cols, analyzer);

 foreach (var word in words)
 {
    BooleanQuery innerQuery = new BooleanQuery();
    innerQuery.MinimumNumberShouldMatch = 1;

    innerQuery.Add(queryParser.Parse(word), Occur.SHOULD);

    mainQuery.Add(innerQuery, Occur.MUST);
 }

 TopDocs hits = searcher.Search(mainQuery, null, int.MaxValue, Sort.RELEVANCE);

 //hits.TotalHits is 0 !!
```

Answer (score 3):

The query you constructed basically requires all three words to match.

You wrap each word in a `BooleanQuery` with a `SHOULD` clause. This is equivalent to using the inner query directly (you're just adding an indirection which does not change the behavior of the query). The boolean query has only one clause, which should match for the boolean query to match.

Then, you wrap each one of these in another boolean query, this time with a `MUST` clause for each. This means each clause must match for the query to match.

For a `BooleanQuery` to match, all `MUST` clauses have to be satisfied, and if there are none, then a minimum of `MinimumNumberShouldMatch` `SHOULD` clauses have to be satisfied. Leave that property at its default value, as the documented behavior is:

> By default no optional clauses are necessary for a match (unless there are no required clauses).

Effectively, your query is (assuming there is no `MultiFieldQueryParser` for simplicity):

```
+(john) +(data) +(check)
```

Or, in a tree form:

```
BooleanQuery
    MUST: BooleanQuery
        SHOULD: TermQuery: john
    MUST: BooleanQuery
        SHOULD: TermQuery: data
    MUST: BooleanQuery
        SHOULD: TermQuery: check
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
BooleanQuery
    MUST: TermQuery: john
    MUST: TermQuery: data
    MUST: TermQuery: check
```

But the query you want is:

```
BooleanQuery
    SHOULD: TermQuery: john
    SHOULD: TermQuery: data
    SHOULD: TermQuery: check
```

So, remove the `mainQuery.MinimumNumberShouldMatch = 1;` line, then replace your `foreach` body with the following and it should get the job done:

```
mainQuery.Add(queryParser.Parse(word), Occur.SHOULD);
```

---

Ok, so here's a full example, which works for me:

```
var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);

var directory = new RAMDirectory();

using (var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED))
{
    var doc = new Document();
    doc.Add(new Field("id", "1", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    doc.Add(new Field("name", "John Smith", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    doc.Add(new Field("additionalData", "faster data", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    writer.AddDocument(doc);

    doc = new Document();
    doc.Add(new Field("id", "2", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    doc.Add(new Field("name", "Alan Smith", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    doc.Add(new Field("additionalData", "faster drive", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    writer.AddDocument(doc);

    doc = new Document();
    doc.Add(new Field("id", "3", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    doc.Add(new Field("name", "Mike Std", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    doc.Add(new Field("additionalData", "faster check", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    writer.AddDocument(doc);
}

var words = new[] {"John", "data", "check"};
var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, new[] {"name", "additionalData"}, analyzer);


var mainQuery = new BooleanQuery();
foreach (var word in words)
    mainQuery.Add(parser.Parse(word), Occur.SHOULD); // Should probably use parser.Parse(QueryParser.Escape(word)) instead

using (var searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory))
{
    var results = searcher.Search(mainQuery, null, int.MaxValue, Sort.RELEVANCE);
    var idFieldSelector = new MapFieldSelector("id");

    foreach (var scoreDoc in results.ScoreDocs)
    {
        var doc = searcher.Doc(scoreDoc.Doc, idFieldSelector);
        Console.WriteLine("Found: {0}", doc.Get("id"));
    }
}
```

Comment: but when I changed the code as you suggested, there are also returned those documents, which doesn't meet the search criteria

Comment: Hmmm it shouldn't have, could you please tell what `mainQuery.ToString()` prints?

Comment: {((name:Joh additionalData:Joh) (name:dat additionalData:dat) (name:chec additionalData:chec))~1}

Comment: You didn't remove `MinimumNumberShouldMatch = 1`, so try to remove that, although I don't think the problem comes from here. The strange part is that it strips the last letter of each word... `StandardAnalyzer` shouldn't do that.

Comment: well, even if I removed the MinimumNumberShouldMatch = 1 the result is the same. It also didn't strips the lat letter, I did it for the example.

Comment: In that case, this query looks perfectly fine to me :-\ did you use the same analyzer for indexing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114553/discussion-between-tony-and-lucas-trzesniewski).

Comment: Sorry, I was offline. I've added a working example to the answer, so you can compare that to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case I stored a string array with the same field name, I had to retrieve all field values from the result `Document`, because the `Document.Get("field_name")` returns only the first column value when there are many fields with the same way

```
var multi_fields = doc.GetFields("field_name");
var field_values = multi_fields.Select(x => x.StringValue).ToArray();
```

Plus, I had to enable the WildCard search, because it fails if I don't type a full word, e.g. `Jo` instead of `John`

```
 string[] words = "Jo data check".Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => string.Format("*{0}*", x)).ToArray();

 var queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, cols, analyzer);
 parser.AllowLeadingWildcard = true;
```